# jQuery append some weird string into the data submitted

Tags: jquery

Code to reproduce the bug (Put the following code in the html page and read the data submitted in Fiddler. jQuery 1.4.2 works fine, the problem happens in 1.5.1 and 1.5.2):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/raw/master/json2.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var data = { "Name": "test??", "testDesc": "testdesc??"};
  $.ajax({ 
    url: "submit.aspx/SubmitData", 
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    type: "POST", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    dataType: "json", 
    cache: false
  }).success(function (msg) {});
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I am using jQuery 1.5.1 for data processing and submit data to the server

```
function test(name, testDesc){
  var data = { "Name": name, "testDesc": testDesc};
  $.ajax({ 
    url: "submit.aspx/SubmitData", 
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    type: "POST", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    dataType: "json", 
    cache: false
  }).success(function (msg) {//......});
}
```

Among one thousand records, there are a few records with string like 'jQuery151023383707909744822_1301931324827' and 'jQuery151033911434971578497_1301989384660' in the data.

Is that the bug of jQuery or any plugins that causes the problem?

More information:
The weird string seems replace the original "?" in those records.
For example,
Do you like StackOverflowjQuery151023383707909744822_1301931324827 I love it very much.
Is this goodjQuery151023383707909744822_1301931324827 It's great.

Update for the bug:
I have reproduced a case for the bug. If I input "test??" for the name, the submitted data becomes "{"Name":"testjQuery15103933552800185728_1302170988810","Description":"fdsa"}"

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't show anything around the records, which given that they're the problem is a bit of an issue. Can you post the relevant parts of the code, the part that builds up the records to send? Also, you've said "...or any plugins..."; rather than us *guessing*, how 'bout telling us what plug-ins you're using?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I wonder why I missed the actual problem.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I have just reported this to the jQuery team.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8798

Comment: Which is a duplicate of [8417](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8417), the fix for which will hopefully find its way into jQuery before too long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**:

<s>Looks like a bug in jQuery to me</s> It is a bug in jQuery, specifically [bug #8417](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8417), which was reported about five weeks ago, closed erroneously, then reopened and there's now a pull request with a fix pending; hopefully the fix will make a future version.

**Workaround below**, but first: This code replicates it in isolation:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $('#theButton').click(function go() {
    var data = { "Name": "test??", "testDesc": "description"};
    $.ajax({ 
      url: "/icece5", 
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      type: "POST", 
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
      dataType: "json", 
      cache: false
    });
  });
});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/icece5/4)

Although we can't see the result of the POST on jsbin.com, we don't care, because it's what we're *sending* to the server that we're worried about. If I send that and look at the request in Chrome's dev tools, I clearly see the data being corrupted with the JSON-P callback name described below.

Interestingly, it doesn't happen if we don't tell jQuery we're expecting JSON back from the server (note the commented out line):

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $('#theButton').click(function go() {
    var data = { "Name": "test??", "testDesc": "description"};
    $.ajax({ 
      url: "/icece5", 
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      type: "POST", 
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
      //dataType: "json", 
      cache: false
    });
  });
});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/icece5/5)

The type of the data being returned shouldn't affect what it does with the data we're sending, I wouldn't have thought. But it does invite a workaround:

### Workaround

```
var data = { "Name": "test??", "testDesc": "testdesc??"};
$.ajax({ 
    url: "submit.aspx/SubmitData", 
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    type: "POST", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    dataType: "text",              // <== Tell jQuery you expect plain text
    cache: false
}).success(function (data) {
    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data); // <=== Then parse it yourself
});
```

<s>Recommend putting together a test case on jsFiddle.net and [reporting it](http://bugs.jquery.com/newticket) to the jQuery team, since you're the person with the real-life problem with it. If it's really a bug, they'll fix it; if not, I'd be interested to know why not...</s>

---

**Original answer**:

The code you've quoted is doing a `POST` of JSON-encoded data, but the strings you've mentioned (`jQuery151023383707909744822_1301931324827`, etc.) are the jQuery "expando" (which is determined at runtime by taking the jQuery version and adding a random value to it) plus `_` plus an epoch value. jQuery creates strings in that form as the default names of JSON-P callback functions, as seen here:

Lines 1,326-1,329 of jQuery-1.5.1.js:

```
// Unique for each copy of jQuery on the page
// Non-digits removed to match rinlinejQuery
expando: "jQuery" + ( jQuery.fn.jquery + Math.random() ).replace( /\D/g, "" ),
```

and (lines 7,029-7,035):

```
// Default jsonp settings
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    jsonp: "callback",
    jsonpCallback: function() {
        return jQuery.expando + "_" + ( jsc++ );
    }
});
```

So my guess is that the code you're quoting isn't the code generating these values, but that you have other code using them.

The name of the JSON-P callback will replace the `?` in the URL of a request if you use JSON-P for the request. I wouldn't expect it to do that in your *data*.

I'd review your use of `ajaxSettings` and such. If you switch to the un-minified version for debugging, you can also set a breakpoint in whatever debugger you use *(and you use one, right? [there's no excuse not to](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html))* on line 7,033 (where those strings are being created) and then step out to find out what part of your code is triggering it.

Comment: jQuery 1.4.2 works fine. The problem happens in version 1.5 or above.

Comment: @Billy: Yeah, looks like a regression. Did you see the workaround?

Comment: ++1 great work! Curious as to why the double ?? are being replaced at all.

Comment: @JohnP: *Purely* because Billy mentioned it at some point, so I plugged that into the test case I was nearly done with. I would otherwise have just gone with one, which apparently would have been fine, but hey, you don't look good test data in the mouth. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

## EDIT

**This reply was posted to the initial question when not much info was available. Read @T.J. Crowder's reply to get the solution for this problem. It's a bug in jQuery and he's posted a workaround.**

---

**Original Reply**

You've asked jquery to make sure the browser doesn't  the request by passing `cache: false` in your options array.

These unique strings are added at the end to make sure that each request is unique and is not cached. Don't worry about it.

Comment: @Billy: You should be seeing them in the query string, though, not the `POST` data. Some server-side frameworks have a "consolidated" way of getting data whether it's in the query string or the `POST` data, but they will also have ways to look only in the appropriate place, making it easier to ignore these.

Comment: @JohnP: It's a good thought, and certainly the values `1301931324827` and `1301989384660` look like epoch values, but that should just be a `_` parameter, not `jQuery151023383707909744822_...` and such. I'm not seeing anything in the jQuery source (1.5.1 rather than .2, I have to admit, but I'm suspecting that matches up with the OP's) that immediately seems to give these values...

Comment: More info is added. The weird string seems replace the original "?" in those records.
For example,
Do you like StackOverflowjQuery151023383707909744822_1301931324827 I love it very much.
Is this goodjQuery151023383707909744822_1301931324827 It's great.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder @Billy, I didn't notice these were part of the records. Definitely shouldn't be showing up in your POST. Is the bug reproducible or does it happen sporadically? Seems like the jquery version and epoch are both added

Comment: I have reproduced a case for the bug. If I input "test??" for the name, the submitted data becomes "{"Name":"testjQuery15103933552800185728_1302170988810","Description":"fdsa"}"

Comment: @Billy user @Salman A might have a solution for you. Does that fix your problem?