# Why is string '??' replaced by 'jQuery15101472...' during ajax call using json and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have an Ajax application using jQuery 1.5.1.
At a certain point in time, I do a Ajax call, posting '???' as an argument.
To my surprise, the value that is read by the server is something like  'jQuery15101472...'.

In the Firebug console, I see that the value posted to the server is already 'jQuery15101472...' in the serialized json request.

How is this possible?

Comment: This really isnt a question at all.

Comment: It's a very unclear question unless you already know about the problem. :-)

Comment: I edited the header and contents to be make the question clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [jQuery bug #8417](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8417), a recent regression related to its JSON-P handling (which it incorrectly applies even if you're not using JSON-P). More information and a workaround in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578754/jquery-append-some-weird-string-into-the-data-submitted/5579420#5579420). The bug is fixed in the source repo and slated to be released as part of v1.6.0.